# LotusNotes How to select and delete a few line with lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

How can i selcted a few Line in a mail ? 13 Lines
with @command([EditSelectAll]) the full mail is selected

I need only the 13 first Line to be selected and after that i will make a import file from this position.

ex : mail with response

> bla
>
> bla
>
> bla
>
> bla
>
> @ dsfadf (hier is the begin from ori mail )
>
> @ safdsf
>
> @ asdfasd
>
> @ fasdf
>
> I will delete only the bla bla string and not the >sdfas  Is Possible
>   to do that ?
>
> ex: ->  @command([EditDown]; 4 ) ;
>
> @Command([Selectonly]; 4 );
>
> @Command([EditClear]);

Thanks  in advence...

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Lotusscript for that.
If the formatting does not matter, you can use regular string handling.
Use the GetUnformattedText method of the NotesRichTextItem class to get the contents of the mail body as plain text. Then you just just Instr(), StrLeft(), StrRight(), Mid$() etc to parse the content.

If you want to keep any formatted text as is, you need to use the RichText classes full out.
You can look at this code for a mailmerge class that I posted a while back, you should be able to use some of the same methods to search for the contents in your mail content:
http://blog.texasswede.com/code-mail-mergeform-letters-in-lotuscript/